# como devolver un numero que sea la resta de la suma de los digitos de la parte entera y la suma de los dígitos de la parte decimal en python

Tags: python

se que este no es un sitio de tareas ni nada por es estilo, pero en verdad no he podido con un punto de un taller que me dejaron en la u, ustedes me podrian ayudar porfavor, he tratado de verlo por alguna parte pero me bloqueo con es de coger la suma de la parte entera y decimal.

Realizar una función que reciba un número mayor (>) que 0 y menor (<) de 1000 con hasta tres
(3) decimales (Ej. 14.201, 28.3, 919.07), y devuelva un número que sea la resta de: La suma de
los dígitos de la parte entera y la suma de los dígitos de la parte decimal.

Ejemplo de números a retornar:
14.201 (5 - 3) => 2
28.3 (10 - 3) => 7
919.07 (19 - 7) => 12

Comment: Hola, te recomendaria que nos mostraras tu codigo, lo que llevas hecho, para asi ayudarte mas facil

Comment: pues mira, dice que tiene que devolver algo asi como estos ejemplos

Comment: Ejemplo de números a retornar:
14.201 (5 - 3) => 2
28.3 (10 - 3) => 7
919.07 (19 - 7) => 12

Comment: Si, lo que sugiero es que nos muestres lo que ya hayas hecho, si es posible

Comment: si me podrian ayudar de como hacer para que python reconozca los enteros y decimales, seria fantastico, esa parte es la que me bloquea

Comment: amigo un pregunta, tu sabes como seria raiz cuadra con operaciones basicas en python? uno me toco hacerlo importando la libreria math y utilizando sqrt, eso si lo se hacer, pero en operaciones basica ni idea

Comment: "*he tratado de verlo*" <-- ¿Podrías mostrar el código con lo que intentaste o qué buscaste en Google y por qué no funcionó?

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque preguntas solicitando ayuda con tareas escolares deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que realizó hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción del inconveniente específico que está teniendo para resolverlo. Por favor lee [ask].

Comment: Se puede hacer de varias formas, aqui tienes la mas facil, me parece que si no puedes realizar este codigo es que tienes poco conocimiento en python o programacion. Por otro lado, si esto es un trabajo escolar, de verdad serviria tener la informacion o el enunciado del trabajo y ver tu avance.
Cambia los --- por tabuladores.

n=raw_input("ingrese un numero : ")
if 0<float(n)<1000:
---n = n.split(".")
---entero, decimal = 0, 0
---for i in range(len(n[0])):
------entero+=int(n[0][i])
---for i in range(len(n[1])):
------decimal+=int(n[1][i])
---print entero-decimal

Comment: Como ya te han comentado para separar la parte decimal de la entera puedes usar el método `split` de las cadenas. Por otra parte referido a tu comentario sobre la raiz cuadrada una forma alternativa a `math.sqrt()` es elevar el número a 0.5. Como tu misma comentas en este sitio no se hacen tareas escolares sin aportar un resúmen de lo intentado y algo de código. Busca información sobre `split`, convertir `str` a `int`, manejo de listas, etc en la web y si te atascas postea tu código y se te intentará a yudar, de lo contrario terminará cerrandose como ésta.